# How to genrate sequence like A1, A2, B3, A4, B5..... in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I want to generate a sequence A1, A2, B3, A4..... like this A and B is based on the column value which contains true and false for true A and for false B.

How I can achieve it??

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete CREATE TABLE statement for the table in question. It sounds as if a generated column might be what you are looking for, but without more details it's nearly impossible to tell. Add the code as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What table column are you talking about? And how to order the boolean values in that column?